# Google+ repeating events

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-events

Is there any way to set up a repeat event for a Google+ group?

I have a group that has regular meetings twice a week and setting up the events manually is really annoying (plus I forget sometimes).

Comment: Do you mean group as in circle or community perhaps? You could schedule a Google Calendar event with a Google Hangout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google+ does not support repeating events. This is the currently offered date/time options for events.

[image]

Comment: Can you substantiate this with some documentation, please?

Comment: Google generally doesn't provide documentation for features they don't provide.

Comment: I realize, but without something to substantiate it (even a brief summary of what they *do* currently support would work), it's hard for it to stand on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You can go under 'details' of an existing event and choose 'Duplicate Event'. This is the only way I know of currently to get anything approaching a occurrence.